# keeping vectors from shrinking back to their original size when animating

Tags: javascript, vector, svg, raphael

in my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7QA43/8/
i've set the vector to 3x it's size and on rollever it's soppose to just rotate 90 degrees,but instead it shrinks back down to it's original size. is there a way to keep this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `s3` to your transform animation.

```
function hovering(e){
         this.animate({
            transform: 'r90,s3',
             'stroke-width':'5'
        }, 500);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7QA43/9/

Comment: it still seems to shrink a bit. does raphael have a way to permanently increase a path vector's size?

Comment: Not for this because when you animate the `transform` attribute, you override any other transformations. So the `s3` transformation will animate back to normal.

Comment: thats a huge limitation for raphael

Comment: You can use http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.transformPath to get a scaled path if you want it to be scaled always (or you could just do the math beforehand to make sure your path is correctly sized).